# Gradient Descent: two different ways, but why the one without scaling in directional derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I have been studying gradient descent and I came across something in its formula.

I realized that if we go in the negative direction of gradient ascent, we can reduce $f$ the fastest. The direction is:

$$
-1 \times \frac{\nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||} 
$$

where, x is the point we are standing at. So, it SEEMS that to update x, with step size parameter "$step$", we can do:

$$
x\_updated = x - step \times  \frac{\nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||} \\ (eq. 1)
$$

(Because, it means: $\Delta x = - step \times \overrightarrow{u}$, where $\overrightarrow{u}$ is unit vector, representing the direction of gradient ascent)

---

But, instead, I saw the following:

$$
x\_updated = x - step \times  \nabla f(x) \\ (eq. 2)
$$

I think the reason to use the latter one (eq. 2) is that we want to have bigger change when $||\nabla f(x)||$ is larger and have smaller change when $||\nabla f(x)||$ is smaller. So, we use that setting in eq. 2 and we do not use the scaled version (eq. 1)

I was wondering if my intuition is correct, and if there is any other reason that I might be missing here.

ALSO, please correct my wordings if you think I used a wrong term for something.

ALSO, if you think this question is duplicate, please provide me with the link as I couldn't find this exact question somewhere else.

Comment: In both cases you need to pick the ‘step’ parameter small enough - so if (as it is usually the case) the modulus of the gradient is bounded (say $||\nabla f(x)||\le M$) you only need to make the step $M$ times smaller and use the 2nd formula. OTOH, the 2nd formula gets away with the need to calculate the modulus *in each step* - i.e. it is more efficient for practical purposes. Plus, division with small numbers (near the minimum) introduces additional instability due to rounding - which 2nd formula avoids.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for the comment! I think I get your point. The second one is preferred because we can avoid calculating that modulus in each iteration, and it avoids potential numerical errors. Also, I think if we want to use eq.1, we need to update the step itself in each iteration. Am I correct? (when the modulus get smaller, we want to scale "step" accordingly as well)